# Changing java.home within build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to change the org.gradle.java.home (or: System.properties['java-home']) **within a build.gradle** before compiling, but had no success at all.

I can't really set -Dorg.gradle.java.home at command line or org.gradle.java.home at the properties file, but really need to set the JDK folder to a location determined in build.java. We use specific JDK/JRE versions for specific versions of our software, and I am resolving the actual java_home path with a gradle plugin. So far so good, but I seem to be unable to change java-home within the script. Or rather, I can do so, but it has no effect anymore.

I also tried to use the JavaToolchainService, but it seems to only let me select one of the Java versions it detected when gradle was fired up.

But I need to set a different path dynamically detected during the configuration phase of the build script. Is that even possible?

If not, is there a way to author a gradle plugin for the JavaToolchainService that makes it find java versions no on the path (or rather: on a path provided in the build script?)
Or run another subproject before that changes java.home for this subproject?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution myself that works for my scenario.

"myPlugin" is the plugin that actually finds the correct path (or downloads it from a server if not already existing locally).

```
myPlugin {
  sdk 'zula-sa-jdk' version '17.44.16'
}

compileJava.dependsOn('myPluginsTask')
tasks.named('myPluginsTask') {
  doLast {
    compileJava.options.fork = true
    compileJava.options.forkOptions.javaHome = myPlugin.getPath('zulu-sa-jdk') // returns a string with the local path to the dependency defined above.
  }
}
```

Note that with this solution, you **must not** use

```
java {
  toolchain {
    // languageVersion=... or such
  }
}
```

otherwise you get an error from gradle.